# Postgres not using enough CPU during index build!

Tags: performance, postgresql

I have a Postgres instance building a GIN index. It's looking at about 200,000 rows and it's so far taken about 9 hours. Who knows how long it will take eventually. The problem is that it's using about 2% of CPU when I'd like it to use more like 90%. Is there any way to force it to speed up?

Comment: Are you sure the performance is CPU bound?

Comment: No I'm not sure. I'm just surprised by the amount of CPU it isn't using. A dump of the whole table comes to 130 MB. It's using 2.6% CPU and 2.7% RAM with enough of each spare.

Comment: Did you set a proper amount of RAM for maintenance_work_mem ? Edit: There isn't a lock blocking the making of the index?

Comment: @Frank - I set maintenance_work_mem to something more sensible and it's now at 99%. I'm much happier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main bottleneck is probably disk IO and not CPU.

If you're on a Windows machine, you can check disk IOs using Process Explorer (freeware), if on Unix, use iostat, sar, DTrace (haven't done the latter in a while so not 100% sure of the best tool)

Comment: The Resource Monitor on Windows also shows this and you can usually easily see there whether the machine is currently CPU-limited or by IO.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on unix (Linux & Mac). I'll take a look at the options.

Comment: I think it was due to paging, leading to thrashing. The answer was to increase the working memory by `set maintenance_work_mem = 102400;`.